calculate $\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=b} \frac{dz}{z^2+bz+1}$
Well, as I understand it, the integrals of this form take the value of zero, since $|z|=b$ is a simple closed curve in addition
$$\frac{1}{z^2+bz+1}$$
It is analytical on that curve away from the zeros of the denominator, so I could determine where that function cancels out and use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem to determine that this integral has a value of $0$ (provided that the zeros in the denominator do not belong to $|z|=b$).
but, how to determine the zeros of that denominator, any suggestions or extra methods? thanks for your help!

Good old quadratic formula?

Sure, I would get something like $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4}}{2}$ from which, what can I deduct?

Let's call these roots $r_{\pm}$. You have to discuss, when $\lvert r_{\pm}\rvert < b$. Take e.g. $r_+$: If $b>2$, then $r_+ \in \mathbb{R}{<0}$.  Then you might see that in this case $\lvert r+ \rvert -b  =- r_+ - b<0$ holds (a little tedious to prove, but certainly not too hard). From this you can deduce that $r_+ \in B_{b}(0)$ (i.e. it is a singularity that has nontrivial residues in that domain). You should then also investigate whether $r_- \in B_b(0)$ and compute the integral. Then do the same for $b \in (0, 2)$. This will give you non-real roots $r_{\pm}$. The last case is $b=2$.

You cannot apply the Cauchy-Goursat theorem until you know where the poles of the integrated function lie. You also have to be sure that the theorem is still applicable if all poles lie inside the contour. And if $b=1$ the poles lie on the contour.
